# Change the text of attributed string in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am using attributed string to add some text to my `UILabel` and I want to change this text when user press the `UILabel`.

Here is my code:

```
let likes: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, CGFloat(totalHeight + 5), 50, 21));
let likesString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString (string: String(selectedItem.noLikes))
var myString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")
myString.appendAttributedString(likesString)
likes.attributedText = myString
mainScrollView.addSubview(likes)
```

What I want to change the value of `likesString` from `(selectedItem.noLikes)` to `(selectedItem.noLikes + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
//I assume that you are getting like label instance on tap action on it

 let likesString: NSAttributedString = likes.attributedText
 let str:NSString = likesString.string

 var intValue:Int = str.integerValue
 intValue = intValue + 1 //increased value by 1

likes.attributedText = NSAttributedString (string: String(intValue))
```